# Lombok wont copy @JsonFormat annotation to getter method

Tags: java, annotations, lombok

I think it is a bug on Lombok library or I am missing something really stupid here.

I have a pojo class

```
@Setter
@Getter
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AnnounceV2 {

@JsonProperty("postedAt")
   @JsonFormat(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", shape = JsonFormat.Shape.STRING, lenient = OptBoolean.TRUE)
   private Date postedAt;


}
```

and i've a lombok.config file:

```
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier
lombok.copyableAnnotations += org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
lombok.copyableAnnotations += com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFormat
```

But even with this configuration `ObjectMapper` was still serializing that field as ISO date... I lost at least 3 hours and debugged a lot then I decided to look at the generated sources folder in my project

there i fould:

```
@JsonProperty("postedAt")
   @JsonFormat(
      pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss",
      shape = Shape.STRING,
      lenient = OptBoolean.TRUE
   )
   public void setPostedAt(@JsonProperty("postedAt") final Date postedAt) {
      this.postedAt = postedAt;
   }


 @JsonProperty("postedAt")
   public Date getPostedAt() {
      return this.postedAt;
   }
```

the jsonformat annotation is only being copied at the setter, so the objectmapper really can't have a clue on how i want to serialize this field.

Am I doing something wrong?
I am missing some detail?

I know i can define a customserializer and do whatever i want... but it is not the point